# Android Studio - Automatically create java class variables from inflated views

Tags: java, android, variables, view

I have a lot of views on my activity that I'd like to be able to both get the value from as well as load a value into once the view has been inflated. It's annoying to have to create class specific variables, class specific getters, and class specific setters for each one of the fields. It seems like it should be a no-brainer to have a hotkey or something that automatically creates a variable that targets a view you're looking for and also generates the getter and setter functions for that specific view type.

Obviously some views are harder than others to create getters and setters for but basic fields like textboxes, checkboxes, etc should be super easy.

With that said, does anyone have any advice to keep me from spending a whole day doing manual labor?

Thanks

Comment: Skip the getters and setters.

Comment: True that's an option, and probably what I should just do since I'm annoyed. It is slightly cleaner looking to create the getters and setters and sometimes saves repeated code but you're right that they can be unnecessary. 

But it still doesn't change the fact that I gotta provide a dam view id for every view I want to edit in the XML layout and then go ahead and then write multiple lines for those exact same views again in the java class, once to declare it and another time to provide it the link to the actual field after layout inflation.  It just gets tedious.

Comment: And thanks everyone for the responses so far. I've read through them and they're all exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out the [android Data Binding library.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Android Annotations.

For Example

```
EditText editText;
TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    .....
    myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
}
```

The above lines can be replaced by

```
@ViewById(R.id.passwordEditText)
EditText myEditText;

@ViewById(R.id.passwordText)
TextView textView;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) will automatically give you getters setters constructor blah blah
and for views [this](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) will help eliminate findviewbyid

Answer (score 0):

I have written PHP code, just paste your xml file into a test.txt (after creating it) file and run the PHP code.  You will need xamp to run php code on your laptop.  I am quite sure a smaller and better code can be written.

```
<?php

$keyword = 'android:id=';

$file = 'test.txt';
$contents = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file));
$array = explode("\n", $contents);
$arrayToSearch = array_map('trim', $array);


customSearchIvVariable($keyword, $arrayToSearch);
echo "</Br></Br>";
customSearchIvBinding($keyword, $arrayToSearch);
echo "</Br></Br>";
customSearchTvVariable($keyword, $arrayToSearch);
echo "</Br></Br>";
customSearchTvBinding($keyword, $arrayToSearch);

function customSearchIvVariable($keyword, $arrayToSearch) {
    foreach ($arrayToSearch as $key => $arrayItem) {

        if (stristr($arrayItem, $keyword)) {

            $arrayItem = html_entity_decode($arrayItem, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $arrayItem = str_replace('android:id="@+id/l_people_you_may_like_', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace('"', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace('_', ' ', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = ucwords($arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace(' ', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = lcfirst($arrayItem);

            if (strpos($arrayItem, 'iv') !== false) {

                echo $arrayItem . ", ";
            }
        }
    }
}

function customSearchIvBinding($keyword, $arrayToSearch) {
    foreach ($arrayToSearch as $key => $arrayItem) {

        if (stristr($arrayItem, $keyword)) {

            $arrayItem = html_entity_decode($arrayItem, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $arrayItem = str_replace('android:id="@+id/l_people_you_may_like_', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace('"', '', $arrayItem);

            $arrayBinding = $arrayItem;

            $arrayItem = str_replace('_', ' ', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = ucwords($arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace(' ', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = lcfirst($arrayItem);

            if (strpos($arrayItem, 'iv') !== false) {

                echo $arrayItem . " ";
            }

            if (strpos($arrayBinding, 'iv') !== false) {

                echo "= itemView.findViewById(R.id.l_people_you_may_like_" . $arrayBinding . ");" . "</br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

function customSearchTvVariable($keyword, $arrayToSearch) {
    foreach ($arrayToSearch as $key => $arrayItem) {

        if (stristr($arrayItem, $keyword)) {

            $arrayItem = html_entity_decode($arrayItem, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $arrayItem = str_replace('android:id="@+id/l_people_you_may_like_', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace('"', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace('_', ' ', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = ucwords($arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace(' ', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = lcfirst($arrayItem);

            if (strpos($arrayItem, 'tv') !== false) {

                echo $arrayItem . ", ";
            }
        }
    }
}

function customSearchTvBinding($keyword, $arrayToSearch) {
    foreach ($arrayToSearch as $key => $arrayItem) {

        if (stristr($arrayItem, $keyword)) {

            $arrayItem = html_entity_decode($arrayItem, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $arrayItem = str_replace('android:id="@+id/l_people_you_may_like_', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace('"', '', $arrayItem);

            $arrayBinding = $arrayItem;

            $arrayItem = str_replace('_', ' ', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = ucwords($arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = str_replace(' ', '', $arrayItem);
            $arrayItem = lcfirst($arrayItem);

            if (strpos($arrayItem, 'tv') !== false) {

                echo $arrayItem . " ";
            }

            if (strpos($arrayBinding, 'tv') !== false) {

                echo "= itemView.findViewById(R.id.l_people_you_may_like_" . $arrayBinding . ");" . "</br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```